# How to position an image in a div for different dimensions?

Tags: css, html, dimension

I am trying to stick a picture to right of the screen with a fixed height. But this way the dimensions do not fit right in different browsers. I cannot upload pictures, so it's quite hard to describe...

```
#profile_pic {
    float: right;
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 12;
}

#profile_pic img {
    width: 12.73em;
}
```

I tried it with %, but it also didn't work this way...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#profile_pic {
    float: right;
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 12;
    height: 100%
}

#profile_pic img {
    width: 12.73em;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4NWB6/)

Answer (score 0):

remove float:right... it will not work on absolute position, set the height and width, can you also post your HTML